# How can we use local wav, mp3 or other audio file as notification sound in React native

Tags: android, react-native, audio, push-notification, notifications

I want to use custom notification sound for my react native app, notification tones are coming from API in form or downloadable url.I want to choose from that audio to use as notification sound.

I am aware of placing audio files in raw folder and using it but in my case it's not possible.

I try using react-native-notification-sound.